# How to sort array in descending order in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an array which is storing some count and I want to sort that array in descending order. In order to get the element first with greater count. Can anyone please tell me how to sort the array in descending order. I am currently using array_sort() but its sorting in descending order.

Comment: Maybe [`rsort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

Comment: For a useful answer without guessing you should provide an example array and what you tried already.

Comment: collect($yourArray)->sortBy('Key','ASC')->values();

Answer (score 3):

If the structure of the array is simple, use the [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php).

If not, use the `array_sort()` and then use the [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$sortedDesc = array_reverse(array_sort(....));
```

Answer (score -1):

in Laravel you can achieve this like

for Ascending

```
collect($yourArray)->sortBy('Key','ASC')
```

for Descending

```
collect($yourArray)->sortBy('Key','DESC');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Try  `->sortByDesc('key')`